# How to find if elements of list in another list? Spring Data JPA @Query

Tags: java, spring, jpa

So, I will try to explain my goal here.

```
@Query("SELECT vr FROM VehicleRequest AS vr WHERE " +
        "?1 IN (SELECT uu.unit FROM UserUnit AS uu WHERE uu.unit.deleted = false AND " +
        "uu.appUser.id = vr.appUser.id AND uu.startAt <= current_timestamp AND uu.endAt >= current_timestamp )")
List<VehicleRequest> getFilteredRequests(Set<Unit> units, Pageable pageable);
```

What I'm trying to do here is the following,
At least one of the elements of the units parameter is in the result of the following SELECT query.

I don't think IN statement is correct here so when I test its not showing anything.

Sorry if I couldn't explain what I wanted better.

Comment: have you tried "SELECT vr FROM VehicleRequest AS vr, UserUnit AS uu WHERE uu.unit.deleted = false AND uu.appUser.id = vr.appUser.id AND uu.startAt <= current_timestamp AND uu.endAt >= current_timestamp AND uu.unit in :units" 
'IN' takes in a collection, or set of parameters, and while JDBC/JPA doesn't support collections, your provider can rework the set's values into individual parameters with the statement it generates.

Comment: it works now but i have to use distinct vr when selecting because it multiplies the records. trying to find another way but couldnt so far.